# Jacks car rental problem: why deterministic policies?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-process

In Sutton & Barto Book: Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction,
there is the following problem:

[image]

I have this question: why are the policies to be considered here are deterministic?